# How to set Google Play `inAppUpdatePriority` using google-php-api-client

Tags: php, android, google-api-php-client, google-play-developer-api

I found following thread at : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133299031#comment14

> Hello, In-app update priority of the release can be set using the Play Developer Publishing API's [⁠Edits methods](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits). There is a new 'inAppUpdatePriority' field under ⁠[Edits.tracks.releases](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/tracks). The documentation does not mention the new field yet but you should still be able to set it. In-app update priority can not be set from the Google Play Console at the moment.

I am using google-api-php-client with Service Account authentication, I would like to ask how to set 'inAppUpdatePriority' using google-api-php-client I have tried following in my PHP code.

```
$publisher->edits_tracks->update(self::PACKAGE_NAME, self::EDIT_ID, 'production', new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Track);
```

Comment: are you able to found any solution, i'm also look for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of testing with [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), I managed to edit the `inAppUpdatePriority` field, with Laravel, this way:

```php
try {
   $packageName = "your.package.name";
   $versionCode = "version_code_as_string"; //example "50"
   $client = new \Google\Client();

   //you need to setup your own Service Account or other API access methods
   $client->setAuthConfig("path/to/your/json/file");
   $client->addScope(AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER);
   $service = new \Google\Service\AndroidPublisher($client);

   //create new edit
   $appEdit = $service->edits->insert($packageName, new \Google\Service\AndroidPublisher\AppEdit());

   //uncomment if you want to get hold of available tracks
   // $tracksResponse = $service->edits_tracks->listEditsTracks($packageName, $appEdit->id);
   // dd($tracksResponse);

   $trackRelease = new \Google\Service\AndroidPublisher\TrackRelease();
   $trackRelease->versionCodes = [$versionCode];

   //set desired update priority
   $trackRelease->inAppUpdatePriority = 5;
   $trackRelease->status = "completed";
   $postBody = new \Google\Service\AndroidPublisher\Track();
   $postBody->setReleases([$trackRelease]);

   //desired track to update. One of the followings: production,beta,alpha,internal
   $track = "production";
   $update = $service->edits_tracks->update($packageName, $appEdit->id, $track, $postBody);
   //commit changes to Google Play API
   $service->edits->commit($packageName, $appEdit->id);
   // dd($update);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
   if ($ex->getCode() == 404) {
       //this catches if some info is wrong (tested with a version code that has not been upload to Google Play Console)
   }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. You should note that for this to work (without implementing your propre way of uploading app via Google Play API), you need to first upload your app via Google Play Console to your desired track, then click **Save**, then **Review release** and ***/!\DON'T CLICK Rollout release/!***, then run the above mentioned code which will Commit (Rollout) the changes (if you try to rollout release after running the above code, you will get an error that you can ignore).
2. Any changes to `inAppUpdatePriority` won't be applied if your release is already rolled out.
3. You should have already published at least one release in the desired track before you can use this (tested with Internal testing only)

Comment: Hi I have uploaded build on Internal Testing Track and set the priority and everything worked fine but when I promoted the same release to Production, priority value is not there. Can you help?